# React Native Maps. Google maps returns back to initial location unable to drag the map around

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Unable to drag the map around, after using google auto complete to search for the location. The map is able to change to the location. However I am unable to drag the map around, its stuck to the center of the location that I searched.

MapContainer.js is used to render the map and componentdidmount is used to retrieve the coordinates of busstops which will be displayed as markers under the render  below

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import MapInput from "./MapInput";
import { getLocation, geocodeLocationByName } from "./location-service";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MapView, { Marker, StyleSheet } from "react-native-maps";
const MyMapView = (props) => {
  return (
    <MapView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      region={props.region}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      onRegionChange={(reg) => props.onRegionChange(reg)}
    >
      {props.busstopArray.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Marker
            key={item.bus_stop_id}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: Number(item.latitude),
              longitude: Number(item.longitude),
            }}
            title={item.name}
          ></Marker>
        );
      })}
    </MapView>
  );
};

class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    region: {},
    busstop: [], //busstop is an empty array, in which the JSON values will be added, to be used later in the code.
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getInitialState();
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ route_id: "1" }, { route_id: "2" }),
    };
    fetch(
      "https://laravelsyd-fypfinalver.herokuapp.com/getBusStop",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ busstop: data });
      });
  }

  getInitialState() {
    getLocation().then((data) => {
      //import locationservice
      console.log(data); //prints out intial region coords
      this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: data.latitude,
          longitude: data.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.003,
          longitudeDelta: 0.003,
        },
      });
    });
  }

  getCoordsFromName(loc) {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: loc.lat,
        longitude: loc.lng,
        latitudeDelta: 0.003,
        longitudeDelta: 0.003,
      },
    });
  }

  onMapRegionChange(region) {
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  render() {
    const bus_stop = [...this.state.busstop];
    // console.log(bus_stop); //testing to see if can display the json objects and it can
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <MapInput notifyChange={(loc) => this.getCoordsFromName(loc)} />
        </View>

        {this.state.region["latitude"] ? (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <MyMapView
              region={this.state.region}
              onRegionChange={(reg) => this.onMapRegionChange(reg)}
              busstopArray={bus_stop}
            />
          </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default MapContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add draggable in Marker:

```
<Marker
                  draggable
                  coordinate={{
                    latitude: Number(this.state.location.latitude),
                    longitude: Number(this.state.location.longitude),
                  }}
                  onDragEnd={e =>
                    this.setState({location: e.nativeEvent.coordinate})
                  }
 />
```